# Updating item in dynamo with multiple expression, can't get delete working with SET

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Trying to use multiple expression SET and DELETE. everything works fine for SET, But when i add DELETE, not able to figure out right syntax.

```
status = "Previously Deployed version"
message = "New version deployment started"
NewVersion  = "PipelineTestAPI_1.5.0"
json_ = {":val1" : status,
         ":val2" : message,
         ":val4" : NewVersion
         }
dynamo_json = ast.literal_eval(d_json.dumps(json_))

json_key = {"Environment" : "PipelineTestAPI-Prod"}
dynamo_key = ast.literal_eval(d_json.dumps(json_key))

resp = dynamo.update_item(
    TableName = "CICDDeployment_Tracker",
    Key = dynamo_key,
    UpdateExpression = "SET currentstage = : val1, message = : val2 DELETE :val4",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = dynamo_json
    )
print resp
```

Error:

> Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: ":val4", near: "DELETE
>   :val4"

Answer (score 0):

It should be `REMOVE` instead of `DELETE`, and `REMOVE attributeName` not the `value`

```
UpdateExpression = "SET currentstage = : val1, message = : val2 REMOVE newVersion",
```